# Keras (Tensorflow) Reshape Layer input error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have a reshape input error and i don't know why.
The requested shape is 1058400, what is (1, 21168) multiplied with the batch size of 50.
What I do not understand is the apparent input size of 677376.
I don't know where this value is coming from. The layer before the reshape is a flatten layer and I directly use the shape of it when I define the target shape of the Reshape layer.

The Model compiles just fine and I use Tensorflow as the backend, so it is defined before runtime. But the error appears only when I put date in to it.

Code:

```python
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

import keras.backend as K
from keras import Model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, Input, Reshape
from keras.optimizers import Adam

config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(sess)

input = Input(batch_shape=(50, 230, 230, 1))

conv1 = Conv2D(
    filters=12, kernel_size=(7, 7), strides=(1, 1), padding="valid", activation="relu"
)(input)
conv2 = Conv2D(
    filters=24, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding="valid", activation="relu"
)(conv1)
conv3 = Conv2D(
    filters=48, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="valid", activation="relu"
)(conv2)
conv4 = Conv2D(
    filters=48, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(5, 5), padding="valid", activation="relu"
)(conv3)

conv_out = Flatten()(conv4)
conv_out = Reshape(target_shape=(1, int(conv_out.shape[1])))(conv_out)
conv_out = Dense(128, activation="relu")(conv_out)

rnn_1 = LSTM(128, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(conv_out)
rnn_2 = LSTM(128, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(rnn_1)
rnn_3 = LSTM(128, stateful=True, return_sequences=False)(rnn_2)

value = Dense(1, activation="linear")(rnn_3)
policy = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(rnn_3)

model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=[value, policy])
adam = Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=adam)

model.summary()

out = model.predict(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(50, 230, 230, 1)))
print(out)
```

Summary:

```python
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (50, 230, 230, 1)    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (50, 224, 224, 12)   600         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (50, 220, 220, 24)   7224        conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (50, 109, 109, 48)   10416       conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (50, 21, 21, 48)     57648       conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)               (50, 21168)          0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
 __________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)               (50, 1, 21168)       0           flatten[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (50, 1, 128)         2709632     reshape[0][0]                    
 __________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                     (50, 1, 128)         131584      dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   (50, 1, 128)         131584      lstm[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                   (50, 128)            131584      lstm_1[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (50, 1)              129         lstm_2[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (50, 5)              645         lstm_2[0][0] 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 3,181,046
Trainable params: 3,181,046
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**EDIT:**

Error for the above code:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 45, in <module>
    out = model.predict(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(50, 230, 230, 1)))
  File "/home/vyz/.conda/envs/stackoverflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1157, in predict
    'Batch size: ' + str(batch_size) + '.')
ValueError: In a stateful network, you should only pass inputs with a number of samples that can be divided by the batch size. Found: 50 samples. Batch size: 32.
```

Comment: Could you provide __actual working code__ to replicate your issue? `Input` has no argument `batch_size`. I suppose, otherwise, this code is not the source of your issue.

Comment: Please verify that my edit is actually about __your root issue__ and the solution below resolves it. I'm almost sure that's what you are after, but would like a second check of OP. In case it's not edit your question appropriately (including code which one can run).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edition of question

**Important:** I have edited your question so it actually runs and represents your problem. `Input` should take `batch_shape` as provided currently. Next time please make sure your code works, will be easier.

### Solution

Solution is quite simple; your batch passed to the network has wrong dimension.

`677376 / 21168 = 32` it is **the default size of the batch** which is expected by [predict](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict). You are supposed to specify it if it's different (50 in your case), like this:

```
out = model.predict(np.random.randint(1, 5, size=(50, 230, 230, 1)), batch_size=50)
```

Everything should work fine now and remember to specify batch size if you want it hardcoded.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, now it runs, how could I missed this. 
thanks you.